# Moving from EF6 to EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

I just started moving my MVC5 project with EF6x to MVC Core and EF Core but have a big problem with my entities configuration's. How you can migrate a EF6 Fluent configure to EF core? 
I need a guide with sample if possible.

Here is one of my mapping classes and my try

**EntityMappingConfiguratuin**

```
public interface IEntityMappingConfiguration
{
    void Map(ModelBuilder b);
}

public interface IEntityMappingConfiguration<T> : EntityMappingConfiguration where T : class
{
    void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder);
}

public abstract class EntityMappingConfiguration<T> : EntityMappingConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    public abstract void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<T> b);

    public void Map(ModelBuilder b)
    {
        Map(b.Entity<T>());
    }
}

public static class ModelBuilderExtenions
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetMappingTypes(this Assembly assembly, Type mappingInterface)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == mappingInterface));
    }

    public static void AddEntityConfigurationsFromAssembly(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Assembly assembly)
    {
        var mappingTypes = assembly.GetMappingTypes(typeof(IEntityMappingConfiguration<>));
        foreach (var config in mappingTypes.Select(Activator.CreateInstance).Cast<IEntityMappingConfiguration>())
        {
            config.Map(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class CommerceServiceDbContext : AbpDbContext
    {
        public CommerceServiceDbContext(DbContextOptions<CommerceServiceDbContext> options) 
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.AddEntityConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
        }
    }
```

**Simple old configuration**

```
public partial class AffiliateMap : EntityMappingConfiguration<Affiliate>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Affiliate> b)
    {
        b.ToTable("Affiliate");
        b.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        b.HasRequired(a => a.Address).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AddressId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

**My Try**

```
public partial class AffiliateMap : EntityMappingConfiguration<Affiliate>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Affiliate> b)
    {
        b.ToTable("Affiliate");
        b.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        b.HasOne(a => a.Address)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AddressId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

}
```

I've done this using Google Search and Microsoft Documentation. But I'm not sure of my work. Since I have +100 configure classes, I'll ask you before continuing. I apologize if the contents of my question are not compatible with the terms and conditions of the site.

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: @Sefe No, I removed EF6 NuGet so I cant compile before fixes all of my entities. Just wanted know my try is done or not

Comment: The only conversion tool I know is a human developer.

Comment: Your conversion looks ok. What is concerning you? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @GertArnold You right. I just started core 2, human developers never asked for true way? Maybe I'm going wrong! It will take me tens of hours . Asking isn't bad, try it

Comment: For a test run you can configure only a part of your entities and the rest later. There is no replacement for trying it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent reading my post @IvanStoev

Comment: @Sefe True. I created simple project for that. My project haven't Test unit. Maybe is time to add. Thank you.

Comment: Also, note that EF core has different mapping options than EF6. For example, many-to-many with hidden junction class is not supported, but other options have been added, like more ways to model one-to-one associations and using alternate keys. That's probably one of the reasons why automated conversion has never been implemented.

Comment: @GertArnold good tips thank you!! Please add this as post with suggestion link

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a good article about moving to EF core. I want share that and keeping this question for starters like me.

**Code Updates** 
Namespace `System.Data.Entity` replaced by `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` replaced by `ValueGeneratedNever();`
The base constructor of `DbContext` doesn't have a single string parameter for the connection string. We now have to inject the `DbContextOptions`
`OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` becomes `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`. Simple change, but change all the same
`modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` is no longer available which means that `EntityTypeConfiguration` is also not available, so I had to move all my entity configuration to `OnModelCreating`
`((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` is no longer available. I was using that to extend the `DbContext` to convert all dates in an out to Utc. I haven't found a replacement for that yet.
`ComplexType` is no longer available. I had to change the model structure a bit to accomodate this.
`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` is no longer available so I had to add the below to my startup.cs

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SbDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
}
```

`WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` becomes `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`
`HasOptional` is no longer relevant as per post
`IDbSet` becomes `DbSet`
`DbSet<T>.Add()` no longer returns `T` but `EntityEntry<T>`

```
var entry = context.LearningAreaCategories.Add(new LearningAreaCategory());
//that's if you need to use the entity afterwards
var entity = entry.Entity;
```

`IQueryable<T>.Include(Func<>)` now returns `IIncludableQueryable<T,Y>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`, same applies for `OrderBy`. What I did was moving all the includes and orderbys to the end.

Source: [Moving from EF6 to EF Core](https://passos.com.au/moving-from-ef6-to-ef-core/)